# Hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I need help in modeling a set of tables/classes in my project. I also need help on how to do the hibernate mapping for these tables. I have following tables in my project.

1. Person
2. Organization
3. Contact
4. Address

Person table can have one or more addresses. Organization and Contact can have only one Address. So I have added the following columns to establish the relationship between the tables.

Address table has PersonId [Since one Person can have more than one address].

Organization and Contact table has AddressId [Since these tables can have only one address].

1. I want to know what java classes I need to create for these tables. Currently I have Person, Address, Organization and Contact classes. Not sure how to link Address class to Person, Organization and Contact class.
2. I want to know whether I should consider Address as a Component or an Entity. And how create the xml mapping Address is considered as a Component.
3. The PersonId in Address table may have null values for the Address records created for Organization and Contact. I fine with creating a separate table [say Person_Address] to store list of addresses for a person. But having this link table might give an provision for many to many relationship between Person and Address tables. How do I enforce one to many relationship in this case.

Comment: OK. So what did you tried till now?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for what you suggest in 3.
By using a OneToMany relationship on the set of addresses in the Person class the intermediate table will be created automatically and I guess it will have a unique constraint on the address id.

Edit: You will only get a reference in the address table if you add a corresponding many-to-one annotation in the address class and use the and map the one-to-many annotation to that field. But since your not doing that you'll get a Person_Address table even with a one-to-many relationship without creating any extra classes.

You should model your classes like you would in plain java. I.e Person would have a set of addresses, the others will have just one and the Address class is oblivious of the others.

Then you add a @OneToMany annotation in the Person class and @OneToOne class in the others.  Or you put that in your orm.xml, although annotations is much better for maintenance.

As for Component/Embedable vs Entity I would suggest entity as it is the simplest and no limitations. Don't use to many concepts at once, and stick to the main road.

Comment: It's generally bad form for a table to have references to other tables that are sometimes null. I supposrt Barsju's answer because Hibernate can handle the restriction of the one-to-many relationship.

That said, a many-to-many relationship isn't going to be a problem, in all likelihood. If two organizations have the same address, shouldn't those objects point to the same entity?

Comment: @NathanielFord: I would consider your example an exceptional case and rather have duplication of the address in this case. What if one of the organizations move. You would risk changing the address of both of them. And this is typically a field I would use Cascade all on, which will not work with many-to-many. With many-to-many you will get lots of unnecessary overhead..